# How to convert basic qt connection into while loop

Tags: c++, qt

I've got from QCstomPlot such code:

```
connect(&dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(realtimeDataSlot()));
dataTimer.start(0); // Interval 0 means to refresh as fast as possible
```

Could someone please help how to make from this connection basic while-loop which will be included in constructor?

expected code:

```
while (2ms timeout)
{
realtimeDataSlot()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with the timer? You shouldn't do anything like long-running loops in the main thread (that'd block the UI). So either use the timer, or move the while loop to a separate thread.

Comment: To do that, you must subclass QThread and put your loop to its *run()* method. You should never block event loop of main thread with a sleep or other blocking wait.

Comment: In my program I used: connect(&dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), customPlot, SLOT(realtimeDataSlot())); Although it seems: "The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot." In QCustomPlot example there is constructor:ui->setupUi(this) +function: void MainWindow::realtimeDataSlot()
{
  ui->customPlot->graph(0)->addData(key, value0);
}                                                                   In VS constructor I've got: ui.setupUi(this);
and due to it I cannot access to customPlot through ui->customPlot. Any Idea for workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QElapsedTimer` in place of a `QTimer`. For example:

```
QElapsedTimer timer;
timer.start();

while (timer.elapsed() < 2)
{
    realTimeDataSlot();
}
```